# Formating strings with comptime values in Zig

Tags: string, formatting, metaprogramming, zig

I am trying to create a polymorphic function that accepts only built-in vectors (as in `@Vector`) of length 4. From what I understand, the length of vectors are comptime known, and I would like to add more information in the compile time error message. I know that `@typeName` can be used to convert types to comptime strings, but what can one use for comptime values?

```
/// x[3] == 1
/// x must be a built-in vector of length 4
pub fn ispoint(x: anytype) bool {
    const T = @TypeOf(v);
    switch (@typeInfo(T)) {
        .Vector => |info| {
            if (info.len != 4) {
                // TODO: report length of provided argument
                @compileError("Not a valid tuple, found Vector of length ???");
            }
            return v[3] == 1;
        },
        else => @compileError("`ispoint` expected a `@Vector(4, T)`, found " ++ @typeName(T)),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Zig standard library has `comptimePrint` for comptime string formating in `std.fmt` ([docs](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#std.fmt.comptimePrint))

```
@compileError(std.fmt.comptimePrint("Not a valid tuple, found a vector of length {}", .{info.len}));
```